# 403 forbidden to my apache server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I set up an apache sever, this is my conf file in "sites-availiable":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhostname.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/cock/phpmyadmin/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin-error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin-access.log combined
        <Directory /home/cock/phpmyadmin>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                # add here your IP addresses
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`
I changed that directory mode to 777, but still can't access the homepage.

Comment: even though you changed the directory to 777 (which you should not do as it is a security threat!!!) you may not have changed the permission of the files in the directory unless you applied the permissions recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Apache now needs `Require all granted` under `<Directory>`, so edit like this :

```
....
<Directory /home/cock/phpmyadmin>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    # add here your IP addresses
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

Then reload config apache with

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```